# Issue with `Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to generate a ViewModel that conforms to a Protocol `Protocoling`, the protocol is generic, and has an associated type.
There are a few ViewModel's that conform to the protocol, so I am trying to create a factory for the viewModel.
I have encotuntered the following error by Swift:
`Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`
Example code:

```
protocol Protocoling {
    associatedtype modulingType
    var data: modulingType { get }
}

enum MyTypes {
    case myName
    case myAddress
}

class NameViewModel: Protocoling {
    let data: String

    init(name: String) {
        data = name
    }
}

class AddressViewModel: Protocoling {
    let data: [String]
    init(address: [String]) {
        data = address
    }
}

class DataFactory {
    func viewModel(forType type: MyTypes) -> Protocoling {
        switch type {
            case .name: return NameViewModel(name: "Gil")
            case .address: return AddressViewModel(address: ["Israel", "Tel Aviv"])
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in `func viewModel(forType type: MyTypes) -> Protocoling`.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: From the current example I think a factory model is not the best one. Maybe you could consider another way of doing it? For example using an enum with associated values (see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).

Comment: @Qbyte I thought about it, but the enum represents a state in my flow,
And according to the state I initialise a ViewModel, the thing is, I don't want to bound the enum to a viewModel.

Comment: It's very easy to fix, just add a generic type with conformance to your data factory, see my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a protocol with an associated type (PAT) as a return type like that without more constraint because the compiler needs to know which type to use.

In your case you must use a technic called the type erasure to be able to work with **any** *Protocoling*:

```
class AnyProtocoling: Protocoling {
  let data: Any

  init<U: Protocoling>(_ viewModel: U) {
    self.data = viewModel.data as Any
  }
}

class DataFactory {
  func viewModel(forType type: MyTypes) -> AnyProtocoling {
    switch type {
    case .myName:
      return AnyProtocoling(NameViewModel(name: "Gil"))
    case .myAddress:
      return AnyProtocoling(AddressViewModel(address: ["Israel", "Tel Aviv"]))
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow you to "erase" the associated type of your protocol and return an `Any` version of your view model.

In order to understand why the PAT needs to work like that I like the following example: the `Equatable` protocol (which is a PAT):

```
static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

This function uses the `Self` type which is an associated type. You want to use it in the next generic function:

```
func areEquals(left: Equatable, right: Equatable) -> Bool {
  return left == right
}
```

Here the compiler will trigger this error: `Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Why? Lets take this example:

```
struct tomato: Equatable {}
struct salad: Equatable {}

areEquals(left: tomato(), right: salad())
```

There is no reason to compare tomatoes and salads. The associated type `Self` is not the same. To avoid this error in this case you need to constraint the `Self` type as following:

```
func areEquals<T: Equatable>(left: T, right: T) -> Bool
```

Now you know the `T` are equatables and with the same associated types.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to fix, in your concrete factory implementation you just need to specify a generic for your factory that has to conform to protocol `protocoling`, see code below :

**Swift 4**

```
protocol Protocoling {
    associatedtype modulingType
    var data: modulingType { get }
}

enum MyTypes {
    case myName
    case myAddress
}

class NameViewModel: Protocoling {
    let data: String

    init(name: String) {
        data = name
    }
}

class AddressViewModel: Protocoling {
    let data: [String]
    init(address: [String]) {
        data = address
    }
}

class DataFactory<T> where T: Protocoling {    
    func viewModel(forType type: MyTypes) -> T? {
        switch type {
        case .myName: return NameViewModel(name: "Gil") as? T
        case .myAddress: return AddressViewModel(address: ["Israel", "Tel Aviv"]) as? T
        default: return nil /* SUPPORT EXTENSION WITHOUT BREAKING */
        }
    }
}
```

It's a first step into the wonderful world of abstraction with protocols. You really create some amazing things with it. Though, I have to say, that personally it's not as intuitive as something like inheritance, it's a great little mind bending puzzle for creating decoupled and abstract systems, that are actually far more powerful.

Swift is a great introductory language, and I believe that it's protocol and extension mechanisms make it one of the more complex and interesting languages.

This design pattern is a great way setting up things like dependency injection.